# Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f\in C^1$. Let's assume that $\int_0^\infty f(x)\ dx$ converges and $f'(x)$ is bounded. Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$.

Let's assume by contradiction that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) \ne 0$. Then, there's a sequence of points, $x_n$,  such that $\left|f(x)\right| > \varepsilon$.

Let's assume that $f'(x)$ is bounded by some $M>0$.
Now, we look at $(x_n - \varepsilon/2M, x_n + \varepsilon/2M)$

By Lagrange's MVT, for every $x$ in this neighborhood:

$$\left|f(x_n)-f(x)\right| = f'(c)\left|x-x_n\right| \lt M \left|x-x_n\right| \lt \varepsilon/2$$

Hence, $$\left|f(x)\right| > \varepsilon / 2$$

The thing is, $f$ could change sign.
We only know that there are infinite neighborhoods where $\left|f(x)\right| > \varepsilon / 2$

How do I end this proof right?

Comment: Your integrand is missing.

Comment: Notice that the width of your neighborhoods is fixed, so if there are infinitely many such neighborhoods, then the integral will be infinity.

Comment: Either there's a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ such that $f(x_{n_i})>\varepsilon$, or there's a subsequence such that $f(x_{n_i})<-\varepsilon$.

Comment: I don't get it all the way through; Couldn't there be a situation where all those neighborhoods cancels each other so the integral ends up finite?

Comment: @Elimination: $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^nf(x)dx$ by definition. If you did have such an alternating situation, then the integral would clearly oscillate between two non-zero values as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Could you explain your last claim more rigorously ("oscillate between two non-zero values")? Why two? I can understand it for a specific example, like $\int_0^t \sin x \ dx = -(\cos t - \cos 0)$, and we know that $\lim_{t\to\infty} \cos t$ doesn't exist.

Comment: The claim is wrong. Consider $f(x) = -1$ for every $x\ge 0$. You must have forgot something.

Comment: @user251257, $\int_0^\infty -1 \ dx = -\infty$.

Comment: @Elimination which is less than $\infty$ ...

Comment: Oh I am sorry. It should be $\int_0^\infty$ **converges**. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch: As Jack Lee suggested, if the conclusion is false, then WLOG there is $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $x_n\to \infty$ such that $f(x_n) > \epsilon$ for all $n.$ By the MVT and the boundedness of $f',$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that for all $n,$ $f>\epsilon/2$ in intervals $I_n$ of length $\delta$ centered at $x_n.$ Thus $\int_{I_n} f >(\epsilon/2)\delta$ for all $n.$

Set $F(x) = \int_0^xf.$ Then $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)$ exists. Hence, by the Cauchy criterion, $F(x)-F(y)$ is as small as we like if $x,y$ are large enough. Hence for large $n, F(x_n+\delta/2)- F(x_n-\delta/2)< (\epsilon/2)\delta,$ contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. The last inequality should be with absolute-value, isn't it?

Comment: If it's true for absolute values, it's true without them, yes?